# Using Guice with Play: Injection possible for static fields only

Tags: java, spring, playframework, guice, playframework-1.x

I am a big fan of Play, and I use it in almost any project of mine nowadays. As one of my projects got bigger, though, I decided to include a DI solution. After a brief consideration between Spring and Guice, I stopped on Guice and added the Guice module for Play (http://www.playframework.com/modules/guice-1.0/home).

The problem with it, seems to be the fact that injection works for static fields only. This means that I will have to do stuff like:

```
@InjectSupport
public class MyService {

    @Inject
    static MyBean myBean;

}
```

from (http://java.dzone.com/articles/dependency-injection-play)

which scares me a bit, especially when it comes to testing. I mean, it is true that most of the DI solutions always try to inject singletons, for instance Spring creates a single instance of every bean and injects it, which is kind of the same at the end, but still. Should I have these concerns?

Comment: You can also inject regular member fields. If you inject *only* regular member fields you also don't need the `@InjectSupport` (but you can even mix it). So you should not have these concerns. What would you like to do which doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely can perform Guice injection with Play.

- You should not use the old Guice module (version 1.0).  The tutorial you referred to is also using the old Guice, and old Play (version 1.2!)

  Please take a look of the new Guice module (version 3.0) & Play (version 2.1.1)

  http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaInjection
- When you inject to an instance variable, you need to create controller dynamically

  In your route file:

  ```
  GET     /                  @controllers.Application.index()
  ```

  In your Global.java, you need to override getControllerInstance:

  ```
  @Override
  public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> controllerClass) throws Exception {
      return INJECTOR.getInstance(controllerClass);
  }
  ```

Comment: I am bound to using Play 1.25, therefore I can only rely on that existing module.

Answer (score 2):

In Play 1, you can easily combine normal Guice singletons with statically injected controller fields, the trick is getting the annotation imports correct.

In your play controllers, jobs & test classes that need static injection use the JSR330 annotation versions:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
public class Application extends Controller {
    @Inject private static MyService myService;
    ....
}
```

and for other classes that need @InjectSupport use JSR330/module imports:

```
import play.modules.guice.InjectSupport;
import javax.inject.Inject;
@InjectSupport
public class AnotherClass  {
    @Inject private static MyService myService;
}
```

For the actual (non-static) services instantiated by Guice library, you need to use the Guice annotation versions (note the com.google.inject package):

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
@Singleton
public class MyService {
    @Inject private AnotherService anotherService;  // note non-static injection
}
```

You'll also need an empty Module to kick things off:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
public class MainModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {}
}
```

This should also work for Guice classes created in other ways apart from @Singleton, such as @Provides, although I haven't tried this yet.